How to filter Virtual Machines with a wildcard in Azure SDK
I am working with Azure SDK in Node.js and I want to get Virtual Machines by their prefix because I do not have their complete name.
I tried to use the wildcard but it is not working.
In the arm-resources.d.ts file that contains the types of the @azure/arm-resources they specified that I can use the function substringof but it seems it does not work with tags
My VM have the tags object property as follows
tags: {
  instancename: "WEB-OCP-0003-1"
}

The thing is that I have only the VM prefix WEB-OCP-0003, If id hardcode just the -1 it works but this part is not always 1
This worked for me but I hardcoded the "-1"
const filter = `tagName eq 'instancename' and tagValue eq '${instancePrefix.toUpperCase()}-1'`;

/**
     * @param {GetInstancesFromProviderParams} params
     * @returns {Promise<import("@azure/arm-compute").ResourceSku[]>}
     */
    async getInstancesFromProvider({ instancePrefix, region: _region }) {
        // I tried all of these
        // const filter = `tagName eq 'instancename' and startswith(tagValue, '${instancePrefix}')`;
        // const filter = `tagName eq 'instancename' and substringof('${instancePrefix}', tagValue)`;
        // const filter = `tagName eq 'instancename' and tagValue eq '${instancePrefix}*'`;
        // const filter = `substringof('${instancePrefix}', instancename)`;
        // const filter = `tagName eq 'instancename' and tagValue eq substringof('${instancePrefix}', instancename)`;
        // const filter = `tagName eq 'instancename' and substringof('${instancePrefix}', instancename)`;instancePrefix.toUpperCase());

        // Filter to get VMs whose tags.instancename starts with the specified prefix
        // const filter = `tagName eq 'instancename' and tagValue startsWith(tagValue, '${instancePrefix.toUpperCase()}')`;
        const filter = `tagName eq 'instancename' and tagValue eq '${instancePrefix.toUpperCase()}-1'`;

        const response = await this.resourcesClient.resources.listByResourceGroup(this.resourceGroupName, {
            filter,
        });

        const vms = [];
        for await (const vm of response) {
            vms.push(vm);
        }

        console.log("Filtered VMs:", vms);
        return vms;
    }

